# Child div element not updating/showing?

Tags: javascript, html, css, video

So I'm making a rather simple Chrome extension that's specifically targeted at looping a portion of a YouTube video. User picks `timeA` and `timeB` then the video loops through these two times until stopped by user input.

Below the video I have a progress bar that is supposed to fill with red according to the current time of the video or the "percent". E.g. `width = currentTime/duration*100+"%"`. Basic progress bar.

There are two elements, the grey rectangle (`videoTimeLine`) that is of constant width, and then a red rectangle (`videoProgess`) which is a child of the grey rectangle who's width grows as the `currentTime` of the video gets longer.

The `videoTimeLine` is rendering but `videoProgress` is not. Even when I set it's width to 50% just to see if it shows it still won't render.

Here's my CSS and JavaScript:

Javascript:

```
function WhenVideoLoads()
{
    videoTimeLine = document.createElement("div");

    videoProgress = document.createElement("div");

    videoTimeLine.setAttribute("class", "videoTimeLine");

    videoProgress.setAttribute("class", "videoProgress");

    //....other stuff

    videoTitleBar.appendChild(videoTimeLine);

    videoTimeLine.appendChild(videoProgress);

    setInterval(function () {videoProgress.style.width = (((videoPlayer.currentTime/videoPlayer.duration)*100)+"%");}, 10);
}
```

CSS:

```
.videoTimeLine
{
    width: 100%;
    height: 30px;
    background-color: grey;
}

.videoProgress:
{
    width: 1%;
    height: 30px;
    background-color: red;
}
```

Any help would be much appreciated. Been trying to figure this out for about 2 days and have exhausted my patience on it.

Comment: Looking at your CSS and the error message in my browser console, I'm guessing `.videoProgress:` needs its colon removed.

Comment: @ChrisG Oh. My. Freaking. God. I have been looking at my code for 2 days, scratching my head and wondering what I could possibly be missing. A colon.... It fixed my problem. Thank you very much! :)

Comment: Happens to the best of us =) But like I said, check your browser console. It took me 2 seconds to find it, thanks to that.